# ERROR: unbound method "method name" must be called with "Class Name" instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, methods, matplotlib

I hope you guys can help me out here.
I've been given this error from the following code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\Tarea5.py", line 60, in <module>
    bg.addBandit(b)
TypeError: unbound method addBandit() must be called with BanditGroup instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)
```

The code:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as p
class Bandit:
    power = random.uniform(15,46)
    life = random.uniform(40,81)
    def __init__(self, power, life):
        self.power = power
        self.life = life
class BanditGroup:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.group = [a] #Where 'a' is an object of the class Bandit
    def addBandit(self,b):
        self.group.append(b) #Where 'b' is an object of the class Bandit
        return self.group

howmanygroups = random.randint(4,11)
i = 0
j = 0
while i <= howmanygroups:
    bg = BanditGroup
    howmanybandits = random.randint(1,11)
    while j <= howmanybandits:
        b = Bandit
        bg.addBandit(b) #<-- line 60
        j+=1
    bgposx = random.uniform(0,50000)
    bgposy = random.uniform(0,50000)
    p.plot(bgposx,bgposy,'r^')
    i+=1
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me what's going on here. I started learning python 2.7 about 2 months ago. 
Thanks!

Comment: You didn't actually make any bandits or a group of bandits to put them in. `Bandit` and `BanditGroup` are classes; what your code tries to do right now is analogous to attempting to sit on the abstract concept of a chair, instead of going to IKEA and getting a specific chair to sit on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to (notice the parenthesis around class instantiation):

```
while i <= howmanygroups:
    bg = BanditGroup(a)
    howmanybandits = random.randint(1,11)
    while j <= howmanybandits:
        b = Bandit(power, life)
        bg.addBandit(b) #<-- line 60
```

Comment: Don't forget that the constructors take arguments.

Comment: @user2357112 D'oh! That's correct :) In the haste of the moment, I forgot.

Comment: Yes! It was a constructor with no arguments! I deleted the requested argument on the BanditGroup constructor so now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `addBandit` requires an instance of `BanditGroup` to be used.  Adding `(...)` after the class name will create one:

```
bg = BanditGroup(...)
```

Right now, you have `bg` pointing to the class *itself*, not an instance of it.

The same thing needs to be done here with `Bandit`:

```
b = Bandit(...)
```

---

Note: `...` means to pass in the appropriate arguments.  You made `BanditGroup.__init__` with a required `a` parameter and `Bandit.__init__` with required `power` and `life` parameters.  Since I don't know what you want these to be, I left them out.

Comment: Yup, that was it... My solution was to delete the required element a on the def __init of BanditGroup. Now it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes probably need parens when you create an instance of your Bandit and BanditGroup classes.  Otherwise, you're assigning a class to your variables, not an instance of a class.

EG: bg = BanditGroup()